# Dynamic job scheduling with Quartz

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to implement some job scheduling using Quartz plugin. I have ScheduledTask domain class:

```
class ScheduledTask {
        String dayOfMonth
        Contact suggestedSupport
        String status

        static constraints = {
            dayOfMonth(blank:false,nullable:false)
            suggestedSupport(blank:false,nullable:false)
            status(blank:false,nullable:false)
        }
}
```

I need the logic to go through all **ScheduledTask** instances and do some stuff - for each instance the job will be fired on **dayOfMonth** - for example if **dayOfMonth** value for specific **ScheduledTask** instance is *25* the job for that instance will fire 25th day of every month. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up the section on "Dynamic Jobs Scheduling" in the plugin docs http://grails.org/plugin/quartz

You need to dynamically create a job for each ScheduledTask instance (probably the instance it is created)

It should be relatively easy to follow the documentation and write your code. If you get stuck something, then post a specific question regarding that on SO.

Comment: I noticed that the documentation is still inaccurate and anyone who has tried to execute it as-is would notice that the job gets fired right away. You have to declare an empty triggers block the job class something like class MyJob {

static triggers ={}

def execute(context) {

println context.mergedJobDataMap.get(‘myData’)
}

} I wrote a blog here a couple of years ago and it still holds true I think : http://blogs.quovantis.com/shalvika/2012/04/scheduling-jobs-dynamically-with-grails/

Comment: Updated blog link - http://blogs.quovantis.com/scheduling-jobs-dynamically-with-grails/  (great blog @Shalvika)